# Does Berserkium stack with Glass Cannon and if so how?

Tags: noita

Berserkium increases your damage and blast radius by 5x, while Glass Cannon increases both by 2x.  Do these effects stack?  If yes, do you do 7x damage or 10x damage?  Is it additive or multiplicative?